# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in Redux + Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

The issue is `document` from Firestore can't show in React Component. Initially, I have fetched items in Redux like this.

**src/actions/index.js**

```
export function fetchItem(id) {
  return dispatch => {
    itemsRef.doc(id).onSnapshot(doc => {
      usersRef.doc(id).onSnapshot(user => {
        statusesRef
          .where("uid","==", id)
          .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(snapshot) {
                const allItems = {
                  item: doc.data(),
                  user: user.data(),
                  status: snapshot.data(),
                };
                dispatch({
                  type: FETCH_ITEM,
                  payload: allItems
                });
            }
          }
      });
    });
  };
}
```

**src/reducers/reducer_items.js**

```
import { FETCH_ITEM } from "../actions";

const initialState = {};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_ITEM:
      return action.payload;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And then I fetched `allItems` with `this.props.fetchItem`.

```
class Item extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
     const { id } = this,proops.match.params;
     this.props.fetchItem(id);
  }
}

render() {
   const { item } = this.props;
   console.log("item", item);
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchItem
};

function mapStateToProps({ allItems }) {
  return { item: allItems };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Item);
```

item in console is

```
item:
Object
item: {name: "XXXXXXXXX", image: "XXXXXXXXXXX"}
status: {content: "XXXXXXXXX"}
user: {name: "XXXXXXXX", image: "XXXXXXXXXXXX"}
```

I can get successfully fetched `item` including item, user, and status.
But I cannot get children document.

```
render() {
   const { item } = this.props;
   console.log("item", item);
   console.log("item2", item.item.name);
}
```

It says `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. But name shows in `console.log("item")`.

Comment: past the object that you get from this `console.log("item", item)`

Comment: added `item` in console.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not best practice but I've solved it with the below code:

```
const allItems = {
  ...doc.data(),
  ...user.data(),
  ...snapshot.data(),
};
```